# Remote SIte URL is not fully displayed

Tags: remote-site

Already in remote site settings the remote site url is "http://b345616rdm.th2.sony.fr:6600".. But when I tried to change it as " http://b345616rdm.th2.sony.fr:6600/web_dat_2_1/GetValidData" , it is not getting pasted fully. Again its showing the prev one.
But it got saved successfully.

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this ?

Comment: Remote site setting save base url .  so it will work for you.

Comment: cant get you !! please be more specific

Answer (score 7):

Remote SIte URL just store the protocol + sub domain name + domain name + port number and ignore anything after /

for example if you enter:

https://www.runscope.com/alerts/j0peqpwtrzd7

It will only take https://www.runscope.com

That is how it works.

Once the base URL is added you can request any resource on that server.

Answer (score 1):

In Salesforce Remote site setting only save the base url because in this way it will handle multiple urls.

For example:

```
xyz.com/abc
xyz.com/jkl
```

Now remote site setting only save `xyz.com` . But it can handle both URLs a same time.